# datastax-agents upgrade through Opscenter GUI? tarball or package

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

```
Versions
dse 4.8.2
OpsCenter 5.2.1
datastax-agents 5.2.1
```

Package installation was done to all the above. Would like to upgrade Opscenter to 5.2.3 and upgrade the agents through OpsCenter GUI to match 5.2.3. If this is done, what would be the type of installation done to datastax-agents?

Assuming the installation done to agents through Opscenter GUI will be package installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When installing agents via OpsCenter UI they’d be installed from packages.